# how to Copy 4 different images from one photo and save as different file

Tags: photoshop

I have 1 image which consists of 4 different images which I need to copy and save it as four different images. Is there any easy way to do it as I have more than 100 such images.

Answer (score 1):

Can you supply a dropbox link to one of the images so I can see what you mean?  Do you mean you have one scan of 4 images all on the same layer, and you need to crop 4x and resave individual images?  Or is each image on its own layer?

Are the 100 images all exactly the same layout? If so, you may be able to create an action that would cut down on your time.

If the images are on separate layers, you can use File > Scripts > Export Layers to files...

Comment: It is one scan of 4 images in the same layer..

Link for sample image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_HV0GrGXRVuQ0U3bE5uTGpoeTg/edit?usp=sharing